# Selecting multiple checkboxes in Angular on button click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table in my HTML code in which the rows are generated by AngularJS ng-repeat. Each row contains a checkbox in the first column and other data
in the corresponding columns. I am trying to mark all checkboxes as selected when this button which is present in another div is clicked.

```html
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in myObject track by $index" ng-class-even="'alternate-row'">
    <td name="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.checked" ng-style="row.checkboxStyle" ng-click="setSelectedRow(row)" />
    </td>
    <td>{{ row.data1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.data2 }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The button is as follows:

```html
<div class="btn-group">
 <button type="button" id="selectAll" class="btn btn-default" title="Select All" ng-click="selectAllGrid()">Select All</button>
</div>
```

A method is called on the click of the checkbox that adds that particular row to an array. How will that method be called if I mark the checkbox as checked on click of the button.

Answer (score 2):

use the directive `ng-checked`

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in myObject track by $index" ng-class-even="'alternate-row'">
    <td name="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkAll" ng-model="row.checked" ng-style="row.checkboxStyle" ng-click="setSelectedRow(row)" />
    </td>
    <td>{{ row.data1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.data2 }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

and in your button function

```
selectAllGrid(){
 $scope.checkAll=true;
}
```

Comment: it worked. Thanks mate. But the action that was performed when I clicked the checkbox is not happening.. Also after I click the checkbox manually the button stops working and doesn't select any further.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in myObject track by $index" ng-class-even="'alternate-row'">
        <td name="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.checked" ng-style="row.checkboxStyle" />{{row.checked}}
        </td>
        <td>{{ row.data }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" id="selectAll" class="btn btn-default" title="Select All" ng-click="selectAllGrid()">Select All</button>
  </div>
```

and in your controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.allchecked  = false;

  $scope.selectAllGrid = function(){
    console.log($scope.allchecked);
    $scope.allchecked = !$scope.allchecked
   for(var i =0; i<$scope.myObject.length; i++) {
     $scope.myObject[i].checked = $scope.allchecked ;
   }
  }

  $scope.myObject = [
      {"data": "sdfsdf"},
      {"data": "asdfassafs"},
      {"data": "asesfrsaedfsadfsadsd"}
    ]
});
```

Working plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/RwtJpcZVU7gzr7Qxe0mB?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. Its a great answer. But how to call the function/event that was called when I physically marked the checkbox as checked.

Comment: Don't understand. Can you explain in detail.

Comment: When I manually click the checkbox to check/uncheck it, an event is triggered and I call a method in JS for that event. I populate an array with the values of that row where that checkbox was present. Now when I check/uncheck it with a button, that method is not being fired on checkbox check/uncheck.

Comment: Ok. I updated the plunker. Once see that. If I miss anything tell me.